# Which "ID" extraction is correct?

Tags: logic, security

This question related to attack on the LMAP++ the result of extracting ID from the messages.
In [Passive Attack on RFID LMAP++ Authentication Protocolm, page 188](http://elibrary.palcomtech.ac.id/wp-content/uploads/Cryptology-and-Network-Security.pdf)

```
ID = C ⊕ IDS ⊕ A ⊕ B
```

While in this paper [Security Analysis of LMAP++, an RFID Authentication Protocol](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/193.pdf)

```
ID = C ⊕ IDS ⊕ A ⊕ B ⊕ IDs ⊕ IDs ⊕ IDs
```

where(IDs = PID)

**Which one is correct?**

Comment: 1. It'd help if you identified exactly where in the paper the second equation appears, as it doesn't appear in the form you have listed here.  2. It'd be nice to provide full citations for the papers (title, author, where published) so that if the links stop working readers can still tell what you are referring to.  3.  Your link to the first paper looks like a pirated copy of a Springer LNCS volume, i.e., copyright infringement.  Speaking purely for myself, that seems sketchy.  Do you want to support that kind of thing?  (Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/49427/160917.)

Comment: I can not tell if this is a computer *science* question, or a security engineering question that happens to use formal notation. (Are you aware of [security.SE]?)

Comment: @Raphael This is definitely a computer science question. The paper was published in LNCS after all. [security.se] might entertain this question but there's a good chance they'd consider it too theoretical and would bounce it here or to [crypto.se].

Comment: Please explain your notations. What are ID, C, IDS, etc? What is ⊕ in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't copy the second equation correctly from the second paper.  The equation in the second paper is

[image: eqn2]

In your notation, this is

```
ID =  A ⊕ B ⊕ C ⊕ IDs ⊕ IDs ⊕ IDs
```

Note: the paper has 3 occurrences of `IDs`, not 4 occurrences; your post has 4 occurrences.  This makes all the difference in the world.

Of course, `IDs ⊕ IDs ⊕ IDs = IDs` (follows since `X ⊕ X = 0` holds for all `X`).  Therefore, the second equation is equivalent to

```
ID =  A ⊕ B ⊕ C ⊕ IDs
```

which is equivalent to the first equation.

Thus, if you accurately copy down the equation from the equation from the second paper, you'll find that it is equivalent to the equation from the first paper.